# CakePhp associating comments with posts

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, frameworks, has-many

Following [THIS](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=9_tn7ogNFo4C&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22In%20this%20exercise,%20associate%20comments%20with%20posts%22&source=bl&ots=X1Gx6fTIxh&sig=NKVUAR2Agy3evN6bXIKANJt41LA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pKstU-j-CaSb0AG83YF4&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22In%20this%20exercise,%20associate%20comments%20with%20posts%22&f=false) book I'm trying to do that exercise to associate comments with posts, but I'm not getting it. Here is what I tried:

```
class Comments extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Comments';
    var $hasMany = 'Post';
    var $belongsToMany = 'User';

}

class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = array('Post');



}

class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $belongsTo = array('User');
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Tag');
    var $hasMany = array('Comments');



}
```

Comment: Beware of books that are using syntax that is deprecated for more than a decade

Comment: Which book would you recommend me?

Comment: At least one that is recommending normal codding standards :) http://www.kmrc.in/admin/uploads/CakePHP.1.3.Application.Development.Cookbook.pdf (CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may lie in your Comments class.  I would guess that instead of:

```
var $hasMany = 'Post';
```

it should be:

```
var $belongsTo = 'Post';
```

And since comments also belong to Users, I would remove the line directly below and instead make it:

```
var $belongsTo = array('Post', 'User');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this if I were you

supposed this is my comment table, I will store Post_ID everytime I create a comment.

```
id int,
comment_title text,
comment_body text,
post_id int
```

Simply showing comment via post_id might fit your needs,